# Segue reseting title to original SWIFT

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, xcode7, segue

I have a UIViewcontroller and 4 tableviews in an app. When i click on a button on the UIViewcontroller it segues to a UItableviewcontioler called "Beach". When the user clicks on a cell of the table, it segues back to the UIViewController and displays the selected cells title as the buttons title. The problem that i am having is when i click on a nother button to a tableview and then clicks on the cell, the previous buttons title sets back to the previous title.

The way i have done the above was adding a variable called "select beach" with "some String" in the viewcontrller. After the selection of the cell the variable is change thus changing the buttons title. Although, the problem in doing it this way is that once the view loads again (When segued to another table) it resets to "Some String"

I have been stuck on this problem for ages now! PLEASE HELP!!

PS- I am using swift-2 and Xcode7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, as the string you trying to display is only stored in the memory after you initialized it run time. What you trying to achieve needs the data to be stored on the device and read from there.

Possible and easiest solution for you might be to use `NSUserDefaults`:

```
let persistenceStoreKey = "MyStringKey"
let stringToStore = "MyString"

// Store data
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(stringToStore, forKey: persistenceStoreKey)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

// Get data
let myString = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey(persistenceStoreKey)
```

Please note that NSUserDefaults is best for storing simple values. If you want to store complex structures on the device please consider using CoreData or a 3rd party eg Realm for database abstraction.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, All i am wondering is what roles do both the store-string and persistenceStoreKey variables have and what is the difference in these. @Daniel

Comment: The store string is basically the string you want to store. The key string is the value you use to retrieve the string you stored. Basically you can use the same, but if you want to store a string with a thousand character for instance it's easier to use a shorter key for retrieveing.

Comment: I also want to know if the user has used the NSUserDefult. I tried to do this by using --- if myString == ""{...} but i am still reseting the value once the view loads .. @Daniel

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by "the user used the NSuserDefult"? The user not using anything, you're the one who are implementing the business logic and making the program and behaviour and you have to check these conditions and adjust display logic accordingly. If you store a value then you have to chechk if you need it. If you don't store a value, you can't read it back. I just simply dont understand what you want.